# In Azure Cognitive Search, can I add multiple blobs into a collection of a single record in an index

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a blob container where each folder represents an item that I have indexed in ACS. The folder name is the key for the item in the ACS index. Imagine the following container structure:

```
container {
    item1 {
        blob1,
        blob2
    },
    item2 {
        blob3
    },
    item3 {
        blob4,
        blob5,
        blob6
    }
}
```

I want to be able to run an indexer against the container, extract insights from the blobs with skills, like OcrSkill, KeyPhrases, EntityRecognition, etc.
I know I can use ShaperSkill to get the information for a single blob/document into a format that I like. For example:

```
List<InputFieldMappingEntry> inputMappings = new List<InputFieldMappingEntry>();
inputMappings.Add(new InputFieldMappingEntry(
    name: "content",
    source: "/document/content"));
inputMappings.Add(new InputFieldMappingEntry(
    name: "languageCode",
    source: "/document/languageCode"));
inputMappings.Add(new InputFieldMappingEntry(
    name: "keyPhrases",
    source: "/document/keyPhrases"));
inputMappings.Add(new InputFieldMappingEntry(
    name: "organizations",
    source: "/document/organizations"));
inputMappings.Add(new InputFieldMappingEntry(
    name: "name",
    source: "/document/name"));
List<OutputFieldMappingEntry> outputMappings = new List<OutputFieldMappingEntry>();
outputMappings.Add(new OutputFieldMappingEntry(
    name: "output",
    targetName: "myDoc"));
ShaperSkill shaperSkill = new ShaperSkill(
    description: "Shape to myDoc",
    context: "/document",
    name: "Doc Shaper",
    inputs: inputMappings,
    outputs: outputMappings);
```

And for the indexer itself, I can extract the folder name from the `metadata_storage_path` like this:

```
List<FieldMapping> fieldMappings = new List<FieldMapping>();
fieldMappings.Add(new FieldMapping(
        sourceFieldName: "metadata_storage_path",
        targetFieldName: "key",
        mappingFunction: FieldMappingFunction.ExtractTokenAtPosition("/", 4)));
```

What I don't know how to do (or if I can even do it) is to take multiple references to `/document/myDoc` output field and get multiple entries into a collection in my ACS index. My desired output would be the following:
... (only showing relevant fields here)

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "key": "item1",
            "myDocs": [
                {
                    "name": "blob1",
                    "content": "<content from blob1>",
                    "languageCode": "<languageCode from blob1>",
                    "keyPhrases": "<keyPhrases from blob1>",
                    "organizations": "<organizations from blob1>"
                },
                {
                    "name": "blob2",
                    "content": "<content from blob2>",
                    "languageCode": "<languageCode from blob2>",
                    "keyPhrases": "<keyPhrases from blob2>",
                    "organizations": "<organizations from blob2>"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "item2",
            "myDocs": [
                {
                    "name": "blob3",
                    "content": "<content from blob3>",
                    "languageCode": "<languageCode from blob3>",
                    "keyPhrases": "<keyPhrases from blob3>",
                    "organizations": "<organizations from blob3>"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "item3",
            "myDocs": [
                {
                    "name": "blob4",
                    "content": "<content from blob4>",
                    "languageCode": "<languageCode from blob4>",
                    "keyPhrases": "<keyPhrases from blob4>",
                    "organizations": "<organizations from blob4>"
                },
                {
                    "name": "blob5",
                    "content": "<content from blob5>",
                    "languageCode": "<languageCode from blob5>",
                    "keyPhrases": "<keyPhrases from blob5>",
                    "organizations": "<organizations from blob5>"
                },
                {
                    "name": "blob6",
                    "content": "<content from blob6>",
                    "languageCode": "<languageCode from blob6>",
                    "keyPhrases": "<keyPhrases from blob6>",
                    "organizations": "<organizations from blob6>"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: It's not possible to aggregate multiple blobs into a single field of a document.
Can you describe your use case for the index? For example, is adding a "item" field in the index a suitable replacement? Then you can search by "item" and get all the blobs associated with it, even though each index document is for a single blob.

Comment: No, adding a new item field in this particular index would not work. And to be clear we are talking about a collection field, which is designed to support multiple structured records. If this is not possible, I'll end up creating a separate index for the blobs and have to perform a search across both indexes to get a consolidated set of results. I'm trying to not do that, but if that's what is required, I can.

Comment: The blobs represent attachments to a parent record. I want to be able to have a clear association of the blob index results per blob associated to the parent record that they are attached to. And the key in this index represents the key of the parent record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indexer doesn't offer aggregation across multiple documents into a single index field since its change tracking may process a blob multiple times resulting in non-deterministic results. The solution is to create two indexes, one index for blobs and one index for parent records. You can either use an external process to read from the blob index to update the parent index in batches, which should have simpler aggregation logic but requires managing an external trigger; or use a [Custom Web API skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-web-api) to update the parent index as blobs are processed. The aggregation logic for the custom skill may be  more complex to only selective add to the parent record if the child blob doesn't already exist. Check out the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-interface) on setting up Azure Functions and connecting the skill to the function.

Comment: I did get a solution working with 2 indexes and an external process for merging the blob results into the other index. It's not what I want for the real/final solution. But, if it is the best I can do, at least I have a working solution.